# PGF / LaTeX Backend in Matplotlib via Jupyter Notebook SLURM Job on HPC System

Tags: matplotlib, latex, jupyter-lab, slurm

I am a university student using my university's computing cluster.

I installed Tex Live to my home directory at `~/.local/texlive/`. I have a file called `mplrc`. The `MATPLOTLIBRC` environment variable is set to the `mplrc` file. The `mplrc` file contains the following lines

```
backend:            pgf  

pgf.rcfonts:        false  
pgf.texsystem:      pdflatex 
pgf.preamble:       \input{mpl_settings.tex} 

text.usetex:        true

font.family:        serif
font.size:          12
```

The `mpl_settings.tex` file is in the same directory as the `mplrc` file and contains the following

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

On the cluster I am using, I must submit a SLURM job to run the Jupyter notebook. The example code I am trying to run within the notebook is

```
formula = (
    r'$\displaystyle '
    r'N = \int_{E_\text{min}}^{E_\text{max}} '
    r'\int_0^A'
    r'\int_{t_\text{min}}^{t_\text{max}} '
    r'\Phi_0 \left(\frac{E}{\SI{1}{\GeV}}\right)^{\!\!-γ}'
    r' \, \symup{d}A \, \symup{d}t \, \symup{d}E'
    r'$'
)


def power_law_spectrum(energy, normalisation, spectral_index):
    return normalisation * energy**(-spectral_index)


bin_edges = np.logspace(2, 5, 15)
bin_centers = 0.5 * (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:])

y = power_law_spectrum(bin_centers, 1e-5, 2.5)
relative_error = np.random.normal(1, 0.2, size=len(y))
y_with_err = relative_error * y

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.errorbar(
    np.log10(bin_centers),
    y_with_err,
    xerr=[
        np.log10(bin_centers) - np.log10(bin_edges[:-1]),
        np.log10(bin_edges[1:]) - np.log10(bin_centers)
    ],
    yerr=0.5 * y_with_err,
    linestyle='',
)

ax.text(0.1, 0.1, formula, transform=plt.gca().transAxes)
ax.set_yscale('log')

fig.tight_layout(pad=0)

plt.show()
```

This generates an enormous error message, but the root of it is

```
RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'lp'
```

However, underneath that, I see what I think is the real problem

```
! LaTeX Error: File `article.cls' not found.
```

I've set my `PATH` so that it finds the right `latex` command, but what else needs to be set in order to find the `article.cls` file? It seems like it's something particular to the Python notebook. When running `kpsewhich article.cls` in a terminal within the Jupyterlab interface, the file gets found. But trying `! kpsewhich article.cls` or `subprocess.run(['kpsewhich', 'article.cls'])` within the Python notebook does not find the file.

Comment: What does `ls` and `pwd` show when in terminal, and what does `!ls` and `!pwd` show when in notebook?

Comment: The notebook is in a different folder than my home folder.  In an initial login terminal window (on a login node, not in a SLURM job), `kpsewhich article.cls` doesn't find anything.  After running `export PATH=~/.local/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`  
`kpsewhich article.cls` finds the `article.cls` file. If I submit the Jupyter notebook job before setting the PATH, the Matplotlib can't find the `pdflatex` executable at all. If I submit after setting the PATH, it can find the executable, but then can't find the needed files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I forgot I had run a section of code which set

```
TEXINPUTS=/path/to/some/directory
```

Looks like I missed a `:` in my `TEXINPUTS`, so TeX was *only* looking in `/path/to/some/directory`

The solution was to have

```
TEXINPUTS=/path/to/some/directory:
```

That way it looked in my current directory, but also continued looking elsewhere.